# Python behave: How to check if current step is within 'Background' context or not

Tags: python-behave

Summary:
when producing test reports or test run dumps in -w mode I'd like to supress the stdout output of steps, which are run as Background steps.
I have control over the output produced via an environment variable but I'm not able to detect when to set it, dependent on if the step is in Background or not.
Even better for me would be to be able to tell behave to not capture / output stdout within the background steps execution programatically.

Details:

```
Feature: Foo
    Background:
        Given foo <setup_mode> was run successfully

    Scenario: ...
        Given foo <test_mode> was run successfully
```

step 'foo' produces much output on stdout which I want to switch off when its part of the test Background.
Best would be a @quiet tag over Background where I can set my environ to not be chatty at steps execution but Background tags are not supported in behave.

And here I can't detect via the context or tag where I am:

```
def before_step(context, tag):
```

context._dir does not provide to me if I'm within Background or Scenario.

=> any best practices regarding that?

My current approach is to explicitly switch output via dedicated Given steps (like "And api output is [on|off] ") but since its always the same for Background and Test steps I'd like to have that rather done behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, re-checking the (great) API helped ;-)

Simple answer which works for me, sorry to bother:

```
def before_feature(context, feature, **args):  
    context.background_steps = getattr(
            feature.background, 'steps', 0) or [] 

def before_step(context, step):
    if step in context.background_steps:
        <switch off chattyness>
    else:
        <switch on chattyness>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the idiom "**use tags for setup/teardown**" is a good idea (for what you want to do). Use the `before_tag()` / `after_tag()` hooks for this purpose.

NOTE:

- Tags are not supported for Backgrounds. See Gherkin syntax for that.
- Background steps are merged with the Scenario steps (prepended to the
  Scenario)

Comment: _Tags are not supported for Backgrounds. See Gherkin syntax for that._


Thats the reason why I could not use them for my specific problem - by definition ;-)